# INSERT INTO SELECT - replace one field with NULL

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-into

I'm trying to perform an INSERT INTO SELECT statement, but while I'm doing it I would like one of the fields within the SELECT statement to return NULL rather than what's in there originally.

So far I have:

```
INSERT INTO `archive`
    SELECT *
    FROM `product`
    WHERE `id` = ?
```

I thought about using the following, which doesn't work as it adds an extra field rather than replace the existing one:

```
INSERT INTO `archive`
    SELECT *, '' AS `image`
    FROM `product`
    WHERE `id` = ?
```

I know I could list all of the fields in order to do it, but that would mean I have to update this statement every time I add new field etc.

Is there a way of doing it with the short version as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your two choices are:

1. List the fields individually in the `SELECT` statement
2. Do an `UPDATE` after the `INSERT` to re-set the column to `NULL`

The first is the proper solution, IMO. It makes future maintenance easier (instead of more difficult, as it appears), and makes it much clearer when you (or a new programmer) visits the code 6 months from now.

Comment: Thanks Ken - that's what I thought.